# Git rebase local branch with stable remote branch resulting in merge conflicts

Tags: git, rebase

I have created a local copy of a remote stable master branch. After a few weeks, I checkout that local branch on a private branch and rebase the private branch with the remote stable branch.

There are some changes that I have pushed to the local copy of the remote branch, and same is present in private branch. The remote stable branch also has changes to some of those files. Conflict arises on rebase.

How can I improve to avoid conflicts while rebasing?

Comment: You don't need to. You have to resolve conflicts in your private branch on each rebase. That's how it supposed to work. To avoid this, do rebase more often.

Comment: Rebase is trying to merge the local commits on top of the rebased branch. Rebase should happen at tip of private branch right ?